# R simplify graph edge attribute

Tags: r, igraph

I have a graph with some more than one edge connecting two same vertex but with different atributes. For example I have three edges from v1 to v2, one with attribute A, another with B and the last one with A. The edgelist would be something like this

```
from to  Att
1    2   A
1    2   B
1    2   A
3    4   C
1    3   A
```

Is there a way to simplify that edgelist or the graph, so that there's only one edge between 1 and 2 with att = A,B? 
I tried with

```
g<-graph_from_edgelist(M[,-3])
E(g)$Att<-M[,3]
g<-simplify(g,remove.multiple = TRUE,remove.loops = TRUE,edge.attr.comb=toString)
```

But the problem is that it  repeats the attribute A. when i try to table the edges att i get

```
E(g)$Att
"A,B,A" "A" "C"
```

I'd like to get "A,B" "C", "A". At first i wanted to merge the edgelist in order to get

```
from to  Att
1    2   A,B
3    4   C
1    3   A
```

But i couldnt find the answer, (i know how to split it with the package splitstackshape and the csplit command, but oddly enough it doesnt have a function for doing the opposite thing).

Thanks in advance, sorry if my english isnt the best, not a native speaker

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `aggregate`

```
## Your data
EL = read.table(text="from to  Att
1    2   A
1    2   B
1    2   A
3    4   C
1    3   A",
header=TRUE)

aggregate(EL$Att, EL[,1:2], function(x) paste(unique(x), collapse=","))
  from to   x
1    1  2 A,B
2    1  3   A
3    3  4   C
```

Comment: Thanks! that did it. Just in case someone wants to do it the graph way, with edge.attr.comb = function(x){paste(unique(x),collapse=",")} also works.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @G5W's answer, but with [tidyverse](https://www.tidyverse.org/)/[dplyr](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=dplyr) functions.  I prefer when the grouping variables (*eg*, `from` & `to`) are referred to by name.

```
library(magrittr)
EL %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(from, to) %>% 
  dplyr::summarize(
    x  = paste0(unique(Att), collapse=",")
  ) %>% 
  dplyr::ungroup()
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
   from    to x    
  <int> <int> <chr>
1     1     2 A,B  
2     1     3 A    
3     3     4 C
```